# Jquery Datepicker is working only one and only for one input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have implemented jquery datepicker for the first time in my project and i have two input fields which will take date as input and i have used class selector to in jquery.
My jquery version is jquery-1.11.0.js  and UI is jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js.  But for only one field date picker is opening and that ti it is taking long time to open.

My HTML code is

```
<div>
    <label for="dateFrom" class="desc">
        <fmt:message key="date.from"/>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" class="datepicker" value="" readonly="readonly"  />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="dateTo" class="desc">
        <fmt:message key="date.to"/>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="dateTo" class="datepicker" id="dateTo" readonly="readonly" value=""/>
</div>
```

My Jquery Code is

```
$(function() {
    $('#dateFrom').click(function() {
        $('#dateFrom').datepicker();
    });

    $('#dateTo').click(function() {
        $('#dateFrom').datepicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/2Y7fp/1/)**

If you wan't Date picker for all inputs,

```
$(function() {
    $('input').datepicker();
});
```

Else, for inputs with *datepicker* class.

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

---

And always specify, such functions on DOM ready, instead of on click of the target element.

Comment: Check console for errors, or post your whole html including html with <script> tags. The fiddle is working.

Comment: Some errors are coming but how to make a jsp not include default js files

Answer (score 0):

Probably error in your code.
You tried to create `datepicker` to `#dateFrom` in your `#dateTo` click event. 
It should be

```
 $(function() {
     $('#dateFrom').click(function() {
           $('#dateFrom').datepicker();
             });

     $('#dateTo').click(function() {

            $('#dateTo').datepicker();

        });

    });
```

or simply

```
 $(function() {
     $('.datepicker').click(function() {
           $(this).datepicker();
             });

    });
```